# Find maximize of the function $\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+b^2}-\frac{1}{c^2+1}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, substitution

Let $a,b\in R^+$ such that $ab+bc+ca=1$. Find the maximize of $$P=\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+b^2}-\frac{1}{c^2+1}$$

---

By Wolframalpha i can see that if $a=b=2-\sqrt 3;c=\sqrt 3$ we will have $P=\dfrac 1 4$

WLOG $a\le b$. I proved that $$P=f(a,b,c)\le f(a,a,c)\le 0$$

$$\Leftrightarrow -(a^2-4a+1)^2\le 0$$

My proof is based on the value of $P$ so it's inconvenient if i dont know value of $P$. This inequality is not homogeneous and symmetric so i dont any idead to solve it

Can you help me solve it without using the equality and value of $P$?

Comment: Is $$c$$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: Did you try the method of lagrange multiplier?

Comment: Do you know theory about max and min of a multivariable function? i.e. the gradient, then the hessian matrix criteria etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find $c$:
$$ab+bc+ca=1 \Rightarrow c=\frac{1-ab}{a+b}$$
Sub to $P$:
$$\begin{align}P&=\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+b^2}-\frac{1}{c^2+1}=\\
&=\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+b^2}-\frac{(a+b)^2}{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}=\\
&=\frac{(a+b)(a-1)(b-1)}{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}\end{align}$$
Now it is symmetric and the maximum is achieved at $a=b$:
$$P(a)=\frac{2a}{a^2+1}-\frac{4a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}\stackrel{x=\frac{2a}{a^2+1}}{=}x-x^2\le \frac14 \Rightarrow x=\frac12=\frac{2a}{a^2+1} \Rightarrow a=2-\sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: Why does the maximum occur for $a=b$? In general your statement is wrong. For example $\max\limits_{a\geq0,b\geq0,c\geq0,a+b+c=0}(a^2-ab+b^2)(a^2-ac+c^2)(b^2-bc-c^2)=12,$ where the equality occurs for $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0).$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, are you sure: $a\ge 0, b\ge 0, c\ge 0, a+b+c=0$? which part is wrong? basically, it is similar to your method $x=\cos \frac{\gamma}{2}$.

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$ does not satisfy the constraint: $ab+bc+ca=1$.

Comment: I gave an example, where you statement about an equality case of two variables, is wrong. See please better my previous comment. Your solution is total wrong. Actually, if you see a down voting, so it's not mine.

Comment: It was typo. I meant a+b+c=3

Comment: yes, equality is not valid in all symmetric expressions, but it is in this case, no?

Comment: In our case it's true. But you need to prove this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}$, $b=\tan\frac{\beta}{2}$ and $c=\tan\frac{\gamma}{2},$ where $\left\{\frac{\alpha}{2},\frac{\beta}{2},\frac{\gamma}{2}\right\}\subset(0^{\circ},90^{\circ}).$

Thus, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^{\circ}$ and
$$P=\frac{1}{2}\sin\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\sin\beta-\cos^2\frac{\gamma}{2}=\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}-\cos^2\frac{\gamma}{2}=$$
$$=\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}-\cos^2\frac{\gamma}{2}\leq\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}-\cos^2\frac{\gamma}{2}$$
Can you end it now?

I got that the maximal value it's $\frac{1}{4}.$